# Map results in axios.js Promise

Tags: javascript, bluebird, axios

I want to perform a map operation in the Promise returned by axios.

It would be something like:

```
  this.$http.get('/movements', this.$auth.httpConfig())
  .map(row => {
    return {
      'origin' : row.origin ? row.origin.name : '',
      'destination' : row.destination ? row.destination.name: '',
      'type_code' : row.type.code,
      'type' : row.type.type,
      'amount' : row.amount,
      'description' : row.description,
      'movement_date' : row.movement_date,
      'id': row.id
    }
  }).
  then((response) => {
    this.table = response.data;
  })
```

Of course, this does not work since map function is not included in Promise, it would require some extra lib like Bluebird, but I had no success while integrating it with axios.

Is there a more "axioish" way to do this? Or what would be the simplest way?

Comment: Just replace `.map` by  `.then(arr => Promise.all(arr.map`? (Or in your case, you don't even need the `Promise.all`, just like you don't need two chained `then` calls)

Comment: Just move your map to the .then()? this.table = response.data.map(...

Comment: Thanks both of you, It was simpler than I thought!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is simpler than using another library. Thanks @Bergi and @Ixe.

```
  this.$http.get('/movements', this.$auth.httpConfig()).
  then(response => {
    this.table = response.data.map((row) => {
      return {
        'origin': row.origin ? row.origin.name : '',
        'destination': row.destination ? row.destination.name : '',
        'type_code': row.type.code,
        'type': row.type.type,
        'amount': row.amount,
        'description': row.description,
        'movement_date': row.movement_date,
        'id': row.id
      }
    });
  });
```